# Did Napoleon write an elegy to Imam Hussain?

Tags: france, islam

In this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4XpqnhehP0), noted Pakistani scholar, [Allama Zamir Akhtar Naqvi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zameer_Naqvi) claims (in Urdu) that Napoleon wrote a letter or poem in honour of the historical figure [Imam Hussain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husayn_ibn_Ali), during a war between the French and the English.

This claim is explained in English on [this Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/karvanemurtaza/posts/554486194593521):

> On the eve of the war with the British, Napoleon wrote an elegy to Imam Hussain (a.s.) seeking his help which is beautifully translated into Urdu by Allama Zameer Akhtar Naqvi

This is used as evidence that Napoleon embraced Islam, and based his laws upon it.

A comment on that video claims

> it can be easily googled and more over it is preserved till now in the great French museum

The Facebook page provides the following references:

> Vide, Bonaparte et l'Islam by Cherfils from the Bibliotheque National De France, we find on pages 105 - 125; Vide, David Pidcock to The Sunday Telegraph, contrasting the French hysteric phobia of late with Napoleon Bonaparte's admiration for Islam; Vide, Lincoln: Money Martyred; Omni Publications 1935); Vide, Translations of French Poem by Allama Zameer Akhtar Naqvi

Is this true?
I cannot find any evidence.

I have made a detailed translation of that Urdu poem translated by Allama Zamir Akhtar Naqvi into English and it is over [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5sD2PI0YoRveG9FZ3p0VUhES2s/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is not very likely....

Comment: @FelixGoldberg i didn't get you

Comment: @FelixGoldberg  do you mean to say this is wrong?, well i have googled the book name and found that there is no digitalised version available for that book, but a lot of printed books are available in french language on many sites like amazon.in etc, but the thing is that i don't want to buy it as i don;t have the privilege to speak or understand french, but if i get only scanned copied of that texts, it would be very thankful from my side

Comment: Napoleon was very interested in some aspects of Arabic/Islamic culture, and was interested in support during his invasion of Egypt and supposed move on India in 1798-99. This would be the period to look at.  After this, he probably would have soured on the subject.

Comment: @Oldcat i've found online that the book sourced as a reference in the question was digitalised on 15th june 2006 source ( https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5sD2PI0YoRvbUZ4Tl9YdURjaVk/edit)  but i am unable to download it, can you help me to get it downloaded?

Comment: I did try, but this book doesn't seem to be viewable from Google Books.

Comment: @Oldcat the same thing i did, will there be any other method to get the book other than manually purchasing the printed form of it??

Comment: Maybe you could contact Google for info. I have no idea myself.

Comment: Another idea would be to contact a library for the book.

Comment: Google books has a digitized copy of [Bonaparte et l'islam d'après les documents français & arabes](http://books.google.com/books?id=KSYYAAAAYAAJ).

Comment: @Comintern yes brother, i have found the same thing when i googled the title of that book but i am not able to read it, will you guide me to read that book please

Answer (score 12):

Bonaparte had an interesting approach to Islam. It should be kept in mind that at the time he was Bonaparte - not yet Napoléon- he was in Egypt and he had to deal with and try have Muslims on his side.

Indeed he urged the local authorities to continue their celebrations, including the celebration of Imam Hussein, urged the troops to not intervene and paid a subsidy. The source for this is the very interesting chronicle of contemporary Egyption Abd-al-Rahman al-Jabartî.

He went further and spoke of the need to protect Islam and its superiority. But he spoke only during this campaign. After, there are no references. Accordingly, most historians consider these statements as "tactical". It's not as if Bonaparte or Napoléon had a very firm relation with sincerity...

Further:

- the letter / poem has never been produced (and I don't know what's the "he great french museum");
- the idea of a conversion to Islam is so ungrounded in documents that it can be only understood in the context of Islam / Europe relations (for French Muslims, making one of the largest - for the best and the worst - French historical figures a Muslim it's meaningful);
- A comparison between the Napoleon Civil Code and Islamic Law can only show differences;

So, I don't think it could be true. (Difficult to prove the non existence of a document...).

But the very persistence of the question / myth is interesting and rises very meaningful questions.

Comment: but according to the comments above the book has been found

Comment: The book indeed exists. The fact that the book exists is meaningless for your question. A book exists. A book says a lot of things. Must be verified. It's not because it's written that's true. If you want I'll look for the book, even though it's a quest without meaning.

Comment: could you please do a favour to me by finding that book ?

Comment: I'll try, but am a bit busy for the next few days.